# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator in Spring-boot jsp application

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jstl

I am getting the error while hitting the home page.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagLibraryValidator
```

I have created one spring-boot project where in the home.jsp page I am using the tag

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

In pom.xml I have the below dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
                  <version>2.0.0</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
                  <version>2.0.0</version>
               </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I am using tomcat-10 to run the application.

Comment: Don't mix JSTL 1.2 with 2.0. Mixing different versions of API/impl makes no sense. See 1st abovelinked duplicate. Also note that Tomcat 10 is Servlet 5.0 not 4.0. See 2nd abovelinked duplicate.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, "Also note that Tomcat 10 is Servlet 5.0 not 4.0. See 2nd abovelinked duplicate." - which dependency you mean?